# "with" in a sentence -- the "comitative case"?

Tags: prepositions, word-order, prepositional-phrases

What is/are the correct word order/s in sentences containing "with X" where  one variant is [the subject, together with X ...]?

Here are a few examples of what I have in mind:

1. I went to the cinema on Sunday with my mother.
2. I went to the cinema with my mother on Sunday.
3. With my mother I went to the cinema on Sunday.
4. I went, with my mother, to the cinema on Sunday.

My problem is that to my non-native ears all of these sound more or less okay (although 2. is a bit weird and 4. sounds a bit archaic). So is there a rule?

I've also found that this is supposed to be called an instance of the "comitative case" but haven't found any concise rules explaining usage so far.

Comment: English doesn't have a comitative case; instead we call these preposition phrases headed by _with_- comitative adjuncts. 1. and 2. are perfectly natural, but 3. and 4. are not.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do some research on 'preposition phrases'.

Comment: *On Sunday, I went to the cinema with my mother* also sounds fine. I couldn't give you the rules in this case, though.

Comment: I don't think *"with"* adverbial phrases are much different from other adverbial phrases (like *on Sunday*) in this regard. The order of non-essential phrases (adjuncts) is just generally fairly free. Note that *to the cinema* is possibly a complement rather than an adjunct.

Comment: This _would_ be an example of where the comitative case would be used if English had such a case (or any cases outside pronouns), but it doesn’t. In a language like Finnish, which has an actual – albeit very formal – comitative case, “I went to the cinema on Sunday with my mother” would be “Sunnuntaina menin elokuviin **äiteineni**”, where _äiteineni_ is the comitative case, meaning ‘with my mother’ (the comitative is always plural in Finnish, so strictly speaking it means ‘with my mothers’, but it is used with singular mothers as well).

Answer (score 1):

The **comitative case** pertains to a *relationship of accompaniment* between two participants in an event, called the **accompanee** and the **companion**. *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comitative_case)*

Your instinct re: four is correct; it *does* sound archaic. It's also somewhat clunky and unlikely to be spoken by a native. Three is a bit stilted, too, and probably not something you'd hear often. The most natural-sounding choices are one and two. There's a good possibility you might hear either from a native English speaker.

More to the point, however, they'd probably leave the comitative case behind and say something akin to:

> *My mother and I went to the movies Sunday.*

Comment: Thank your very much for your comment, this was also really useful.

Comment: It isn't so much that number four is after some fashion archaic as that it’s a more specialized use-case than the others because of the way it sets the *“with my mother”* bit off in parenthesizing commas immediately after the verb. It would have its purpose given the right contextual reference frame surrounding it, and the right prose style. The writer will have had some particular reason for introducing the maternal accompaniment in that way.

Comment: I disagree with your final paragraph. It sounds too formal to my British ears, so much so that I can't imagine myself ever saying it in conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Some arguments against your examples being examples of a noun in the comitative case:

There are few ways in which English uses morphology to modify a word, and in each case the modification is to append a suffix to the word. (Or to alter the word-root, if you consider ablaut changes such as mouse->mice to constitute morphology.) No English *morphological* process entails using an additional word. To view a *with*-phrase as a noun in some case would entail a substantial change in our model of English grammar.

A single "with" may govern a noun-phrase which is the conjunction of two or more noun-phrases, e.g. "with my mother and my sister". If some *morphological* process were done, it would be performed on each noun separately, but it isn't, so the use of "with" is not morphological.

The theory that the use of "with" constitutes putting the noun into a case would have to explain how come a word may be inserted between "with" and the noun, e.g. "with either my mother or my sister".

Answer (score 0):

> So is there a rule?

All your sentences are possible given the correct context.

There are no rules in English, only guidance. Some guidance looks like a rule; it probably isn't.

There is a general order to adpositional phrases:

The first order of adpositional phrases in English is subject, verb, Place, Manner, Time: *I went to London (Place) by plane (Manner) last week (Time).*

Usually, if you depart from this, the phrases will be offset by commas.

The second order of adpositional phrases emphasises the time element. In this, the time element comes first: *Last week (Time), I went to London (Place) by plane (Manner).*

The third order of adpositional phrases emphasises the manner element. In this, the manner element comes first: *“With British Airways (Manner), I can arrive in London (Place) at 7 o’clock local (Time).”*

However, English is very flexible with the position in the sentence of adverbs, adverbial phrases and adverbial clauses. Everything depends upon context and which element you wish to emphasise.

The above is simply a general guide: not all the elements of Place, Manner Time may not appear, and sometimes there will be more than one of them. *Every year (Frequency) in August (time), I go with my wife (manner) to Cape Town (place) via Rome (manner) by plane (manner) for our anniversary (purpose).*