# What is the correct word order with the verb 'to move'? 1) I moved with my mother to Spain. 2) I moved to Spain with my mother. Thank you

Tags: word-order

everyone.

1. I moved with my mother to Spain.
2. I moved to Spain with my mother.

Is 'word order' correct in both sentences? If not, what is the grammar rule that applies here?
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Yes, the word order of prepositional phrases is not fixed; either one will work. In speech, one could also vary the stress and rhythm as well.

Comment: Related [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/370677/with-in-a-sentence-the-comitative-case) to help your research.

Comment: They are both fine. You could also say "My mother and I moved to Spain."

Answer (score 1):

It is important to state that the verb (move) is unimportant - it can be any verb.

"with my mother" is a prepositional phrase that, in this case, modifies "moved". It acts as an adverb.

There are no "rules" for adverbs - there is only guidance.

In your case,

I moved, with my mother, to Spain. This requires the commas shown as the adverbial is displaced.

I moved to Spain with my mother. This does not require the commas.

Adverbs, adverbial phrases and adverbial clauses have a default order in English:

The first order of adpositional phrases in English is subject, verb, **Place, Manner, Time**

I went to London by plane last week. --Subject….verb…….Place…….Manner….Time

The second order of adpositional phrases emphasises the time element. In this, the time element comes first:

Last week, I went to London by plane. Time, subject, verb, place, manner. **Note the comma!**

The third order of adpositional phrases emphasises the manner element. In this, the manner element comes first:

“With British Airways, I can arrive in London at 7 o’clock local.” Manner, Subject, verb  Place, Time. **Note the comma!**

However, English is very flexible with the position in the sentence of adverbs, adverbial phrases and adverbial clauses. Everything depends upon context and which element you wish to emphasise.

The above is simply a general guide, all the elements of Place, Manner and Time may not appear, and sometimes there will be more than one of them. Place, Manner, Time can be expanded to Place + Manner + Frequency + Time + Reason + Purpose + Quantity + Quality

and sometimes, there is more than one element in the sentence.

Every year, in August, I go, with my wife, to Cape Town via Rome by plane for our anniversary.

I go to Paris by plane, in first-class, to have a meeting about business on two occasions each year in summer,

Answer (score 0):

Where did you move with your mother? Answer #1.
With whom did you move to Spain? Answer #2.

The word you want to draw attention to ends the sentence.